# Which eclipse plugin should be used?

Tags: pmd

Currently there are two eclipse plugins available. One maintained by Philippe Herlin and one by Philip Graf. Which one should be the preferred one?

See here: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.3.3/usage/integrations.html#Eclipse

Thanks for suggestions and help.

-- EDIT --

The plugin maintained by Philippe Herlin has more customization options in eclipse as far as i can see.

Answer (score 0):

I generally preferred to use and install plugins which can be downloaded from Eclipse update site. for example http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

From “Help”->“Software Updates”->“Find and Install”

Comment: Thx. Currently i tend to use http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/ as well.